# asp.net watin: error occur while performing testing using watin in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, watin

I have used the below code for testing the JavaScript simple validation.
And below is the code I have used for WatiN.

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IE ie = new IE("http://localhost:2034/WebForm3.aspx");
        ie.ShowWindow(WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Maximize);
        var confirm = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
        ie.AddDialogHandler(confirm);
        ie.TextField("TextBox1").TypeText("Pa");
        ie.Button("Button2").ClickNoWait();
        //dialoghandler.WaitUntilExists(5);        
        confirm.OKButton.Click();
        var dialoghandler = new AlertDialogHandler();
        ie.AddDialogHandler(confirm);
        **dialoghandler.OKButton.Click();**//the error is could not find dialog does not exist.
        dialoghandler.WaitUntilExists(10);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For errors in Dialogbox OK click, you can resolve by...

```
ConfirmDialogHandler handler = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher, handler))
{
   //trigger the event to popup dialogbox
   ie.Button("Button2").ClickNoWait();  //Copied from your code
   handler.WaitUntilExists();
   handler.OKButton.Click();
}
```